# MySQL хрорнение изменений и дат

Tags: php, mysql

День добрый, есть таблица (trip_data) в базе данных, в ней 11 колонок, скажем необходимо отслеживать как меняются данные (версии текста до последней обновленной, кто изменил , когда изменил) в колонках 4,5,6 и 9 как это грамотно сделать?? К тому же не могу найти нормальный мануал как в базе данных добавить данные к уже имеющимся?? ТО есть к примеру вести лог ипишников? Каждый раз вытаскивать из базы данных старый аипишник к нему добавлять новый обратно засовывать в базу данных это долго. Есть вроде способ покороче через update! Кому не сложно дайте ссылку на толковый ман?!

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: @Cone, я бы, скорее всего, что использовал бы [триггер][1]. При обновлении записи , автоматом бы записывались необходимые данные в таблицу лога. Можно копировать предыдущую запись с добавлением времени и id того, кто редактировал.

   [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю для логирования изменений в trip_data создайте trip_data_log с полями:

```
дата_записи - можно принять за дату изменения записи из таблицы данных trip_data;
код_записи_данных - код(id) записи из таблицы данных trip_data которому соответствует запись об изменении;
пользователь - изменивший запись пользователь;
старые_данные - данные до изменения (можно и обойтись, ведь предыдущая запись в поле новые_данные и есть старые_данные);
новые_данные - данные после изменения;
```

Таким образом можно отследить изменения любой записи таблицы данных trip_data, с датами и пользователями

Answer (score 1):

Создайте таблицу `history`, куда пишите все изменения, которые нужно отслеживать. Что туда писать - вам видней, навскидку: IP (или id пользователя), время, тип операции, возможно  данные для отката операции (diff), и т.д.

> К тому же не могу найти нормальный мануал

[Да неужели](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20mysql&lr=2)?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю самый тупой вариант версионирования: на каждый коммит создавать новую строку в таблице. Каждый документ имеет уникальный идентификатор (например `doc_id`), при чтении выбирается последняя по дате или `id` строка с заданным `doc_id`. Ну и дополнительное поле указывающее на тго кто создал эту редакцию.

Схему можно несколько улучшить, посмотри например как это сделано в wordpress.

Что касается дописывания значений в ячейку. Это не очень-то вяжется с реляционной моделью хранения данных, она предполагает что каждое самостоятельное значение будет храниться отдельно.

Т.е. вместо:

```
id | name  | ip
1  | vasya | 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
```

нужно делать

```
id | name  | ip
1  | vasya | 127.0.0.1
2  | vasya | 127.0.0.2
```

Конечно есть случаи когда можно обойтись первым вариантом, но имей в виду что это может создать проблемы в будущем.